# How can I be notified when rsyslog disconnects TCP connection from the remote server

Tags: rsyslog

I want to forward logs to remote server.
My question is how rsyslog can notify me when it disconnects/reconnects with remote server.

I write a draft configuration file like below:

```
global(
   DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/home/robot/cacert.pem"
   DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/home/robot/clientcert.pem"
   DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/home/robot/clientkey.pem"
)

module(load="imuxsock")

action(
  type="omfwd"
  protocol="tcp"
  target="127.0.0.1"
  port="6515"
  gnutlsPriorityString="MinProtocol=TLSv1.2
  MaxProtocol=TLSv1.3
  Curves=X25519:P-384
  CipherString=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  Ciphersuites=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
  StreamDriver="ossl"
  StreamDriverMode="1"
  StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/certvalid"
 )
```

It can work but I want it to notify me by sending a mail when it disconnects/reconnects with remote server. Thanks.